# The specified string is not in the form required for an e-mail address

Tags: .net, asp.net, smtp

I search the eror But I found nothing. My Mail setting is well form. Is there any idea what couse of this exception?

Mail Configuration

```
<add key="SMTPFrom" value="mailer@mycompany.com" />
<add key="SMTPReplyTo" value="mailer@mycompany.com"/>
<add key="SMTPCredentialUserName" value="company_mailer_system"/>
<add key="SMTPCredentialPassword" value="password"/>
<add key="SMTPHost" value="hostUrl" />
```

I add some mailaddress `myMail.To.Add(to)` and `to` contains mail addresses splited by `;`

Comment: have you checked with comma separated address in 'to'.

Comment: yes, everthing ok in 'to' value

Comment: I think Patrick's solution will work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to split the addresses in to and add them one at a time

```
string[] addrs = to.Split(";");
foreach (string addr in addrs) {
    myMail.To.Add(addr);
}
```

Comment: i just add 'myMail.To.Add(new MailAddress(addr));' it worked, thanks a lot